# set array values as object key using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like

```
array(
  [0] => value1
  [1] => value2
  [3] => value3
   .
   .
  [n] => valuen
)
```

I want this array values as object key like

```
object{"value1":{"value2":{"value3":"..."}}}
```

How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What will the value be of the inner-most property in the result? The last value from the array? Anyway, the `.reduce()` method or a simple loop will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce`

```
const result = arr.reverse().reduce((acc, cur) => ({[cur]: acc}), {});
```

Example:

```
const result = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].reverse().reduce(
  (acc, cur) => ({[cur]: acc}), {});

console.log(result); // {a: {b: {c: {d: {}}}}}
```